# Firestore retrieve single document by field value and update

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve a single document by a field value and then update a field inside it.
When I do `.where("uberId", "==",'1234567')`, I am getting all the docs with field `uberId` that matches `1234567`.
I know for sure there is only one such document. However, I don't want to use uberId as the document's ID, otherwise I could easily search for the document by ID. Is there another way to search for a single document by a field ID?

So far, reading the docs, I could see this:

```
const collectionRef = this.db.collection("bars");
const multipleDocumentsSnapshot = await collectionRef.where("uberId", "==",'1234567').get();
```

Then I suppose I could do `const documentSnapshot = documentsSnapshot.docs[0]` to get the only existing document ref.

But then I want to update the document with this:

```
documentSnapshot.set({
  happy: true
}, { merge: true })
```

I'm getting an error `Property 'set' does not exist on type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While **you** may know for a fact there's only one document with the given `uberId` value, there is no way for the API to know that. So the API returns the same type for any query: a `QuerySnapshot`. You will need to loop over the results in that snapshot to get your document. Even when there's only one document, you'll need that loop:

```
const querySnapshot = await collectionRef.where("uberId", "==",'1234567').get();
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  doc.ref.set(({
    happy: true
  }, { merge: true })
});
```

---

What's missing in your code is the `.ref`: you can't update a `DocumentSnapshot`/`QueryDocumentSnapshot` as it's just a local copy of the data from the database. So you need to call `ref` on it to get the reference to that document in the database.

Answer (score 1):

```
async function getUserByEmail(email) {
  // Make the initial query
  const query = await db.collection('users').where('email', '==', email).get();

   if (!query.empty) {
    const snapshot = query.docs[0];
    const data = snapshot.data();
  } else {
    // not found
  }

}
```